# Python update reverse geocoding data to sql table

Tags: python, sql-server, google-maps, geojson, pyodbc

From [this](http://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/reverse-geocode-a-set-of-lat-long-coordinates-to-city-country/) source I get to know to read lat long coordinate from a csv file and get the reverse geocoding done, but when I try to do the same but using source as sql table instead of csv file, it gives some syntactical error.
reading data from sql table

```
import pyodbc          
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydb;UID=test;PWD=abc@123;autocommit=True')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select  GEOCODE_ID, lat, longt from GEOCODE_TBL where JSON_str is NULL")
    ID=[]
    px_val=[]
    py_val=[]
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
      ID.append(row[0])
      px_val.append(row[1])
      py_val.append(row[2])



    #code to update the O/P from google reverse geocoding(JSON String) into table

for i in range(1,len(px_val)):
  wp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=false".format(px_val[i],py_val[i]))

  pw=wp.read().decode('utf-8')
  pw = json.loads(wp)
  cursor.execute("UPDATE GEOCODE_TBL SET JSON_str = ? WHERE GEOCODE_ID = ?", str(pw[i]),str(ID(i)))
  print('Done')
  cnxn.commit()
```

Any help on this will be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?